# Rails | let use input data on view without ever storing the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm playing with the twitter gem and came across the following problem

This is my extremely simple view, it's only purpose is to return the first 20 tweets from a given Twitter handle.

**home.html.erb**

```
<%@client.user_timeline("BU_Tweets").each do |tweet|%>
    <p><%= tweet.text%></p>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way for me to create some sort of form on the same page itself which will ask the users something along the lines of "Please enter a twitter handle: ", save that word in a variable, and use the variable in something like this:

```
<%@client.user_timeline(#{twitter_handle}).each do |tweet|%>
    <p><%= tweet.text%></p>
<% end %>
```

I don't see a reason why I need to create an entire model just to store those words.

I googled around and it appears that most people recommends javascript. I don't know any javascript, so I'm wondering if there's a Ruby/Rails approach to this problem?

Comment: From what I gather, you're essentially trying to mimic asynchronous behavior without actually using javascript (which is a bit of a read flag).  The "rails way" to do this would be to do either of the two methods that you're avoiding:  javascript (most optimal) or to use the database.  You might be able to combine `attr_accessor` to create a dummy field, a custom route that can accept the result of that field as a param, and then figure out how to spit the `attr_accessor` string over to your `update method.`  This is, however definitely not the "rails way" nor is it advisable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript, you'll need to have a full page refresh after the user submits the form. Have a form something like this:

```
<%= form_tag <some_url> do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'handle' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'client', @client %>
<%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
```

Route `some_url` to `some_controller#some_action`:

```
def some_action
  @client = #however you're getting @client
  @timelime = @client.user_timeline(params[:handle])
  #render the original page
end
```

Then on that page do:

```
<% @timeline.each do |tweet|%>
  <p><%= tweet.text%></p>
<% end %>
```